# From list of dictionaries filter out, for each item, it's lowest value

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

If anyone who has an idea on how to improve the title feel more than welcome!

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [  
    { 'id' : 1,    'value' : 1 },
    { 'id' : 2,    'value' : 2 },
    { 'id' : 1,    'value' : 2 },
    { 'id  : 2,    'value' : 1 },
]
```

I've sorted it by `key=itemgetter('id','value')` and get

```
list = [  
    { 'id' : 1,    'value' : 1 },
    { 'id' : 1,    'value' : 2 },
    { 'id' : 2,    'value' : 1 },
    { 'id  : 2,    'value' : 2 },
]
```

Now I want to filter out, for each id, it's lowest value to get

```
list = [  
    { 'id' : 1,    'value' : 1 },
    { 'id' : 2,    'value' : 1 },
 ]
```

My current solution is something like this

```
new_list = []
old_id = -1
for item in list:
    new_id = item['id']
    if new_id != old_id: 
        new_list.append(item)
        old_id = new_id
```

But I've seen a lot of cool things done here with filter, map, reduce, lambda functions and list comprehension and started to questioning if there could be a cleaner solution to my problem?

Comment: Look into `itertools.groupby`. But if the code you have works, move on to the next useful part.

Comment: I think you meant to write `new_list.append(item)`

Comment: Thanks Jim, edited it in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the list has been sorted by `id` and `value`, you can group by `id` and take the first item from each group, which should have the lowest value for the *id*:

```
from itertools import groupby
[next(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key = lambda d: d['id'])]
# [{'id': 1, 'value': 1}, {'id': 2, 'value': 1}]
```